# how to read data from the 3 row from excel sheet and convert to datatable

Tags: c#

i am able read the data fine. but now i have an issue.  **i need  to read data  staring from 3  row in an excel sheet. and then  convert the data  to datatable**

**how can i set the  row postion to start reading data from an excel sheet[to reading starting from 3 row]**
 example:

```
 excel sheet
 1 list of names of the people
 2  Employee Name
 3 kumar
 4 kiran
 5 manu
 6 manju
```

so i should  start reading data from  2 row in excel. so that
my datatable will have

```
  Employee Name
     kumar
     kiran
     manu
     manju
```

i am using excel 2007. 
 this is below code i am using is ther any thing tat i need to change.

```
public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string strfilelocation)
{
    OleDbConnection excelConn= new  OleDbConnection();
    DataTable dtPatterns = new DataTable();;
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
        OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(); OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();    
        string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + strfilelocation + "; Extended Properties =Excel 8.0;";    
        excelConn =new  OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);    
        excelConn.Open();    
        excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT `Employee Name` as PATTERN FROM [sheet1$]", excelConn);    
        excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;    
        excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatterns);    
        //"dtPatterns.TableName = Patterns";    
        ds.Tables.Add(dtPatterns);    
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)    
    {    
        WriteError(ex.Message);    
    }    
    finally    
    {    
        excelConn.Close();             
    }    
    return dtPatterns;             
}
```

any help would greatly appreicated. looking for an a solution

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
SELECT `Employee Name` as PATTERN FROM [sheet1$A2:A6]
```

with HDR=Yes in Connection string